# Azure Durable function - InvalidOperationException when CallActivityAsync

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

I'm playing around with the [Azure Durable functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable-functions-overview). Currently I'm getting `InvalidOperationException` within Orchestration function after I call an activity. It complains that *Multithreaded execution was detected. This can happen if the orchestrator function previously resumed from an unsupported async callback*.

Have any one experienced such an issue? What I'm doing wrong?
Complete code can be found on [GitHub](https://github.com/zavolokas/Inpainting/blob/serverless/Samples/InpaintService/InpaintOrchestration.cs)

Here is the line from the orchestration function:

```
var res = await ctx.CallActivityAsync<int>("LengthCheck", "inputData");
```

The `LengthCheck` activitiy function is:

```
[FunctionName("LengthCheck")]
public static Task<int> Calc([ActivityTrigger] string input)
{
    var task = Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
    task.Wait();
    return Task.FromResult(input.Length);
}
```

The stack trace is:

> ac6fd5cdd07a4dc9b2577657d65c4f27: Function 'InpaintOrchestration
>   (Orchestrator)', version '' failed with an error. Reason: 
>   System.InvalidOperationException: Multithreaded execution was
>   detected. This can happen if the orchestrator function previously
>   resumed from an unsupported async callback.
>
> at
>   Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.DurableOrchestrationContext.ThrowIfInvalidAccess()
>
> at
>   Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.DurableOrchestrationContext.d__47`1.MoveNext()
>
> End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)
>
> at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)
>
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This exception happens whenever an orchestrator function does async work in an unsupported way. "Unsupported" in this context effectively means that `await` was used on a non-durable task (and "non-durable" means that it was a task that came from some API other than `IDurableOrchestrationContext`).

You can find more information on the code constraints for orchestrator functions here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-code-constraints.

Here are the rules that were broken in your code when I quickly scanned it:

> - Orchestrator code should be **non-blocking**. For example, that means no I/O and no calls to Thread.Sleep or equivalent APIs. If an orchestrator needs to delay, it can use the [CreateTimer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.webjobs.extensions.durabletask.idurableorchestrationcontext.createtimer) API.
> - Orchestrator code must **never initiate any async operation** except by using the [IDurableOrchestrationContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.webjobs.extensions.durabletask.idurableorchestrationcontext) API. For example, no Task.Run, Task.Delay or HttpClient.SendAsync. The Durable Task Framework executes orchestrator code on a single thread and cannot interact with any other threads that could be scheduled by other async APIs.

This exception specifically occurs when we detect that an unsupported async call is made. I noticed that is happening in this code:

```
    private static async Task SaveImageLabToBlob(ZsImage imageLab, CloudBlobContainer container, string fileName)
    {
        var argbImage = imageLab
            .Clone()
            .FromLabToRgb()
            .FromRgbToArgb(Area2D.Create(0, 0, imageLab.Width, imageLab.Height));

        using (var bitmap = argbImage.FromArgbToBitmap())
        using (var outputStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            // modify image
            bitmap.Save(outputStream, ImageFormat.Png);

            // save the result back
            outputStream.Position = 0;
            var resultImageBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(fileName);
            await resultImageBlob.UploadFromStreamAsync(outputStream);
        }
    }
```

The proper way to make async or blocking calls is to wrap them in activity functions, which don't have any of these constraints.

In more recent versions of this extension (v1.3.2 and greater), we've included a link to the documentation describing code-constraints in the exception message.

Comment: The **[DurableOrchestrationClient](https://azure.github.io/azure-functions-durable-extension/api/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.DurableOrchestrationClient.html)** API should be valid as well, shouldn't it? This is useful for getting the Http​Management​Payload from within the orchestrator.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this solution.
So the way is always -> create activity step and in that method call activity that calls something to get data.

Comment: The link doesn't work as @baouss commented, adding updated link: [DurableOrchestrationClient Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.webjobs.durableorchestrationclient?view=azure-dotnet-legacy)

Comment: I fixed the links in the answer to be up to date (and specifically referenced the V2 APIs). To answer @baouss's question, no, the client APIs are not valid. If you need to use client APIs, do it from an activity function.

Comment: Sorry, but what is an activity function though?

Comment: Nevermind, thanks. I found it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-bindings?tabs=python-v2%2Cin-process%2C2x-durable-functions&pivots=programming-language-csharp#activity-trigger) :D

Answer (score 3):

This was happening for my  durable orchestrator function too. I had to get rid of all the .ConfigureAwait(false) endings for the activity function invocations.

```
 //invoking First activity function
        var id = await context.CallActivityAsync<Guid>(Function1, requestModel);
        

        //invoking second activity function that uses data from the first activity function without ConfigureAwait(false)
        var readModel = await context.CallActivityAsync<ReadModel>(Function2, id);
       

        //invoking third activity function that uses data from the second activity function without ConfigureAwait(false)
        await context.CallActivityAsync(Function3, cartReadModel);
```